# Angular 2 typescript call a void method wait for that method executing to complete before executing next step

Tags: angular

We have a requirement to call a method of return type void, in typescript, but type script should not continue with the next line of code until void method executing is complete. How can we achieve this.

in the below example we have to call saveEventDetails from closeWindow, but in close window  var win = window.open("about:blank", "_self");               win.close(); should not execute until saveEventDetails method execution is completed.

EX:-

```
 saveEventDetails(buttonClick: string = "") {        
        this.eventForm.markAsUntouched(false);
        this.eventForm.value.claimNumber = this.appContext.claimNumber;
        this.eventsService.patch(this.eventForm.value).subscribe(res => {
            this.loadUserTrackingDetails();
            this.userTrackingService.saveUserTrackingDetails(this.userTrackingModel).subscribe(r => {
                if (buttonClick == "") {
                    this.showSuccess();
                }
                return Observable.of();
            });
        }, (errResp: any) => {
        this.errorMessage = "Unable to load EVENT, invalid user or claim number";
            return Observable.of();
        });
    }




    closeWindow() {
        this.eventForm.value.cmResidentStateLicensed = false;
        Observable.create((observer: Observer<any>) => {
            this.saveEventDetails("popup")
            var v = true;
        })            
            .subscribe(data => {                
                var win = window.open("about:blank", "_self");
                win.close();
            },
            (errResp: any) => {
                this.errorMessage = "Unable to Save EVENT, Please try after soemtime";
            });      



    }
```

Comment: The answer is to make that method return an observable, not void. Currently it can't work anyway, because the setting of the error message is independent of the thing you think you're setting it for.

Comment: You should return an observable in your saveEventDetails() function, then subscribe that on closeWindow().

Comment: You forgot to put `;` at the end of the statement. There should be `returned` value. Also `close()` function doesn't work anyway you have to remove it.

Comment: I have return Observable.of(); in saveEventDetails(), same as subscribe in closeWindow(), I am not sure what I am missing here,

Answer (score 0):

Why you're not subscribing the Observable that is returned by the saveEventDetails() ?

```
closeWindow() {
    this.eventForm.value.cmResidentStateLicensed = false;
    this.saveEventDetails("popup").subscribe(data => {                
        var v = true;
        var win = window.open("about:blank", "_self");
        win.close();
    },
    (errResp: any) => {
        this.errorMessage = "Unable to Save EVENT, Please try after soemtime";
    });      
}
```

Comment: if i do subscribe on this.saveEventDetails("popup"), i throwing property 'subscribe' does not exist on type 'Void'